# Force Exclude /usr/lib64/perl5 Library Directory from Custom Perl Install

Tags: perl, gcc, compilation, shared-libraries

I need to create a custom system-wide perl install on a CentOS machine.  I don't want to use perlbrew as I want to alter the config variables myself, plus I get the same linkage problems.

Essentially, I cannot figure out how to compile perl so that /usr/lib64/perl5 is not included by the linker or in @INC.  That is the old centos version, and it sucks.  No matter how I compile though, `perl -V` yeilds this:

```
@INC:
/usr/local/lib64/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/local/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld
/usr/local/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.16.3
/usr/local/perl5/lib/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld
/usr/local/perl5/lib/5.16.3
```

And then when I run, I get insane library errors like this: `undefined symbol: Perl_Gthr_key_ptr` from libraries inside /usr/lib64/perl5.

Note that PERL5LIB has no effect on this, it is compiled in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove a directory from `@INC`, you can use `no lib`.  For example,

```
no lib "/usr/lib64/perl5/";
```

would remove the `/usr/lib64/perl5/` directory from `@INC`.

For more, try `perldoc lib`.